# How to assure that a function return will be an instance of string?

Tags: php

I want to use the FILTER_VALIDADE_EMAIL but it gives me a warning saying that it expects an string. I am new to php, and i am having trouble trying to use OO with it.

```
<?php

Class User {

    private $id;
    private $login_name;
    private $hashed_password;
    private $email;


    public function __construct($login_name, $email){
        $this->login_name = $login_name;
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getLoginName(){
        return $this->login_name;
    }

    public function setLoginName(String $login_name){
        $this->login_name = $login_name;
    }

    public function setEmail(String $email){
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getEmail(String $email){
        return (string) $this->email;
    }
}?>


<?php

include("../lib/php/User.php");

class UserDAO {

    private $user;

    public function __construct(){
    }

    public function getUser(){
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(User $user){
        $this->user = $user;
    }


    public function insertUser(User $user){
        $email = $user->getEmail();
        $login_name = $user->getLoginName();
        //ver http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php
        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && empty($login_name)){
            echo "valid user";
        }
    }
}

$user = new User("user","user@gmail.com");
$userDAO = new UserDAO();
$userDAO->insertUser($user); ?>
```

The error returned is

PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to User::getEmail() must be an instance of String, none given

Comment: Look at the line number... `public function getEmail(String $email)` requires an argument, I'd make it `public function getEmail(){`

Comment: Note the remark in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) though: _"Type hints can not be used with scalar types such as int or string. "_ So, unless you have a `String` class, drop those hints.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has something quite similar to JavaScripts `typeof` function, and it's named `gettype`.

From PHP docs site:

> Returns the type of the PHP variable var. For type checking, use is_* functions.

[Info about this function can be found here.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php)

---

Using this function you can check against your function, if it returns the type of "string", or any other data type you wish.

Since `(string)` is not an object in PHP, you cannot check if it is an instance of a string, unless you create a custom `String Class/Object` for that purpose, which is quite easy.

---

Basic example of `gettype` from PHP docs site:

```
$data = array(1, 1., NULL, new stdClass, 'foo');

foreach ($data as $value) {
    echo gettype($value), "\n";
}
```

Example output of this example would be:

```
integer
double
NULL
object
string
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) anywhere the type hint is String. String cannot be used in type hinting. Same goes for Int.